# Azure Database backup to Local Storage

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I build a web program and hosted it on an Azure Virtual Machine. I'm using the database as Azure Database.

This is the first time I hosted a web application all by programing and finalization and did it by self-studies.

So I want to know when I test it on a local server I used to run a scheduled script that took a daily backup of my database. But when I hosted it on the Azure Database, I couldn't find a way to get a backup of my database. ( It has an option but I have to buy another storage to create a backup. So it costs a additional fee)

Is there any way to get a database backup without paying the additional cost? I can connect to the database using the credentials in my local SQL server. I tried right-clicking the database name and tried to get a backup but the option wasn't there. Then I tried to get it by generating scripts and selecting the option, data, and schema. It fails to take the all data it currently has.

Want to know how you guys doing this. And another thing, The reason why I used a Virtual machine to host my web application and used Azure database as the database is, that I tried installing the SQL Server on the Virtual machine. But from the application, I couldn't connect to the created server on the VM. Followed a few tutorials but couldn't figure it out. So if anyone knows how to do it, please help me to solve it because then I can re-write the auto backup script and get the backup on the VM.

Waiting for a better solution from the experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to get a database backup without paying the additional cost?

You can [Export the database to a BACPAC file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export?view=azuresql)